# Disabling Linux mouse middle button

Tags: mouse, gnome, eclipse, freenx

In Linux by default the middle mouse button (i.e. wheel) copies the selected text into the place of cursor.

This causes accidental pasting while I'm trying to scroll code / config files via the mouse - especially in Eclipse.

Any idea how to disable it?

*Update* :

The main problem is that I'm using FreeNX for remote terminal, and don't have the mouse section in my xorg.conf. I guess it's because FreeNX uses some sort of virtual mouse.

Is it possible to turn it off in FreeNX, or in Gnome windows manager?

Thanks.

Comment: Which window manager are you using, e.g. KDE, Gnome?

Comment: I had a problem like this with the Logitech G5.  I eventually just got a new mouse that wasn't as finnicky instead.

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Comment: For more information see [How can I disable middle click pasting?](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/how-can-i-disable-middle-click-pasting/27034/7)

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, that's a feature that missing on non-X11 platforms.  :)

If you're using KDE or GNOME you should start poking around their respective mouse configuration panels.

Failing that, check http://linuxreviews.org/howtos/xfree/mouse/ This page lists a few ways to tweak your X11 configuration files.

You *may* be able to get away with something like:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 0 3 4 5"
```

Comment: This works, I used it to move the middle button to one of the side buttons.

Comment: What if I'm using FreeNX terminal server, and I don't have the Mouse section in the xorg.conf?

Will it still work if I create a new Mouse section there?

Answer (score 1):

found the answer here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=59730

From the article:
Replace the emulate3button option in your xorg.conf file with this:

```
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 1 3 4 5"
```

This remaps the middle button into the left button, essentially turning the middle-click into a left-click.

Answer (score 0):

Check your window manager preferences to see if there's an easy way to set Button 2 to something else.  If that doesn't work, you can use xmodmap to map that button away.

Answer (score 0):

With `xterm` you can use `-xrm '*.omitTranslation: reset'`. That assigns mouse-button 2 with the meta modifier to the clear-saved-lines action, which stops it having any effect. The other mouse middle button actions still work.

PS: Thanks to Thomas Dickey, the brain behind 'xterm' for pointing out to me what I had missed.